# Return a php value from a form without ajax

Tags: php, html, forms, button

It might be a beginner question but I'm really struggling with this. I want to put a html button in one of my page that will trigger a function. 
But in order to do so I also need a php value from my page to be return from the button to the function.

I don't want to use Ajax for this.

```
//first file
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    theFunction($i);
}
require_once 'file.php';


<?php
//second file
$i = 4; ?>
<form method="POST">
   <input type="submit" name="button"  value="buttonvalue">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send the value via a hidden form field.

```
...
//first file
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $i=$_POST['i']; //<---
    theFunction($i);
}
require_once 'file.php';

//second file
$i=4;
?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"> 
  <input type="submit" name="button"  value="buttonvalue">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//first file
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['INPUT_NAME']) && !empty($_POST['INPUT_NAME']))
    {
        theFunction($_POST['INPUT_NAME']);
    }
}
require_once 'file.php';


<?php
//second file
<form method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="INPUT_NAME" value="YOUR_VALUE_eg-4" requiered/>
   <input type="submit" name="button"  value="buttonvalue">
</form>
```

This method is not secured.
You can only use a simple html link like 
`<a href="first.php/?i=4">TEXT</a>` ou if you make a good router you can use something like `<a href="first.php/4/">TEXT</a>`